# Is it possible to pass props from Link by React Router from a Component to the component by Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This is the code I want to do from the parent Component Home:

```
class Home extends Component {
render() {
    const { environment } = this.props; // <-- this is the props I want to pass
    <Link environment to="/register"> // <-- this is what I want to do
     <RaisedButton label="Register" style={{ margin: 12 }} />
    </Link>
}
```

And this is my React Router configuration code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Route exact path='/(index.html)?' component={Home}/>
      <Route  path='/register' component={Registration}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  mountNode
);
```

There's a prop from the parent component Home that I want to pass on Registration component, How do I do that?

Comment: there's a prop on Home component that I want to pass on Register. It's commented on my scenario sample above

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a state in the Link `to` object like so:

```
 <Link to={{
  pathname: '/register',
  state: { linkState: this.props.myProp }
}}/>
```

Then in the Registration component you can access this state like so:

```
this.props.location.state.linkState
```

For more info see: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: I tried this but I have error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'